# How much memory space does Macro definition takes?

Tags: c, macros

I have a lot of unused macros in my code.
So, I am wondering.. If a macro is unused, does it takes up memory space in your program?

The type of macros I have are just the basic ones.
Example:

```
#define TEST_ID 0
```

Comment: Try to insert a macro like `#define unused this is a silly unused macro for testing purposes, please disregard!!!!!111!11eleventy )))`, compile, and see if it has any effect on file size.

Comment: According to the definition, included MACROS's code will be added while compiling,  in main code.

So during execution it will consume some space in RAM

Comment: @Confused Could you cite the reference that says this? Does it really say that a macro that **is not used** will be added?

Answer (score 6):

Macros will be expanded during preprocessing phase so they don't exist in your program. They just take some space in your source code.

**Edit:**

In response to Barmar's comment, I did some research.

*MSVC 2012*: In debug build (when all optimizations are disabled, /Od), adding lines of macros won't cause the growth of the size of your program.

*GCC*: does provide a way to include macro in debugging information as long as you compile your program with a specific flag. See [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html). (I didn't know that before myself. Thank you, @Barmar, @Sydius)

Comment: Aren't they included in debugging info so you can use them in the debugger?

Comment: I'm not sure. As far as release build is concerned (which that I assume that OP really cares, who cares about the size of a debug build anyway?), I think that holds.

Comment: Some compilers, like Intel's, do include the option to include macro information in the debug info for a compilation unit. I don't know if unused ones would be compiled out, however.

Answer (score 2):

No, doesn't takes space until is used, for this two pieces of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d %s\n", argc, argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEST_ID 0

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d %s\n", argc, argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The ASM generated with `gcc -S` is the same.

Answer (score 1):

macro is replaced by preprocessor before compilng start.
if you define a macro, and doesn't use it, the compiler will never see it.